# month on month sales growth in mysql

Tags: mysql

First of all I am not an expert of database. I create a database at my own and run few queries successfully. What I wanted now to calculate highest ach% of one month over the next and then use the result to compare it with the next month.

For example, I have july ach % and aug Ach % and result of these two months will be compare with sep ach %. What I am doing now using a query is here in the post. What I wanted that how can I do this for all the months in a query?

Code:

```
`associate_monthly_ach_percentage`.`Team Name` AS `Team Name`,
`associate_monthly_ach_percentage`.`CCRS ID` AS `CCRS ID`,
`associate_monthly_ach_percentage`.`Associate Name` AS `Associate Name`,
`associate_monthly_ach_percentage`.`Desgination` AS `Desgination`,
`associate_monthly_ach_percentage`.`Date of Joining` AS `Date of Joining`,
`associate_monthly_ach_percentage`.`Ach % Jul` AS `Ach % Jul`,
`associate_monthly_ach_percentage`.`Ach % Aug` AS `Ach % Aug`,
( CASE
WHEN ( `associate_monthly_ach_percentage`.`Ach % Aug` >=
`associate_monthly_ach_percentage`.`Ach % Jul` )
THEN `associate_monthly_ach_percentage`.`Ach % Aug`
ELSE `associate_monthly_ach_percentage`.`Ach % Jul` END ) AS `Highest Ach Jul to Aug`,
`associate_monthly_ach_percentage`.`Ach % Sep` AS `Ach % Sep`
```

I stuck here, not able to think of how can I compare this result with the month of Sep Ach %. Above query runs perfectly and show required data correctly.
Any help on this will be appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Result of Above Query:

```
Team Name   CCRS ID Associate Name  Desgination DOJ Ach%Jul Ach%Aug Highest AchJultoAug Ach%Sep

Cardio Hospital 102 Musawar Jaan    H.C.R   4/1/2011    122 118 122 103
Cardio Hospital 103 Zulfiqar Ali Khan   H.C.R   7/11/2016   118 118 118 87
Cardio Hospital 104 Hameed Ur Rehman    H.C.R   6/7/2009    90  79  90  103
Cardio Hospital 1101    Muhammad Ahmed  H.C.R   9/3/2011    85  96  96  79
```

**SQLFIDDLE LINK**

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a93816

Dummy data added to check the query.

Comment: Please add data and full query

Comment: Air Changes per Hour?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @AlpeshJikadra Brother please see the link of slqfiddle.

Comment: @NadeemAfzal, Could you please add some insert queries ?

Comment: @AlpeshJikadra Could you please tell me where I put insert queries? I mean in which table?

Comment: in all table from where you are expecting some column values

Comment: What is **ach %** ?

Comment: Achievement of Sales against Target.

Comment: @AlpeshJikadra Data added using insert, you can check now

Comment: @NadeemAfzal, Hi I have executed the select query http://rextester.com/DLWG48936 here , could you please explain how do you want to get data based on this data , I have copied data from your fiddle.

Comment: Could you please add data in **tp** table if required something for calculation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

I have query from your generated table as below,

I hope this will solve your problem,

```
    SELECT
    `associate_monthly_ach_percentage`.`CCRS ID` AS `CCRS ID`,
    `associate_monthly_ach_percentage`.`Associate Name` AS `Associate Name`,
    `associate_monthly_ach_percentage`.`Date of Joining` AS `Date of Joining`,
    `associate_monthly_ach_percentage`.`Ach % Jul` AS `Ach % Jul`,
    `associate_monthly_ach_percentage`.`Ach % Aug` AS `Ach % Aug`,
    GREATEST(`associate_monthly_ach_percentage`.`Ach % Jul`, `associate_monthly_ach_percentage`.`Ach % Aug`) AS `Highest Ach Jul to Aug`,
    `associate_monthly_ach_percentage`.`Ach % Sep` AS `Ach % Sep`,
    GREATEST(`associate_monthly_ach_percentage`.`Ach % Aug`,`associate_monthly_ach_percentage`.`Ach % Sep`) AS `Highest Ach Aug to Sep`,
    `associate_monthly_ach_percentage`.`Ach % Oct` AS `Ach % Oct`,
    GREATEST(`associate_monthly_ach_percentage`.`Ach % Sep`,`associate_monthly_ach_percentage`.`Ach % Oct`) AS `Highest Ach Sep to Oct`,
    `associate_monthly_ach_percentage`.`Ach % Nov` AS `Ach % Nov`,
    GREATEST(`associate_monthly_ach_percentage`.`Ach % Oct`,`associate_monthly_ach_percentage`.`Ach % Nov`) AS `Highest Ach Sep to Nov`,
    `associate_monthly_ach_percentage`.`Ach % Dec` AS `Ach % Dec`,
    GREATEST(`associate_monthly_ach_percentage`.`Ach % Nov`,`associate_monthly_ach_percentage`.`Ach % Dec`) AS `Highest Ach Sep to Dec` FROM
`associate_monthly_ach_percentage`;
```

Comment: please see the below link and query result.

[1]: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8502f7/5
  [2]: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8502f7/5/0
  [3]: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8502f7/5/1

What I wanted in [3] there is a column Highest Ach from Jul to Aug, I wanted to get Highest Ach from Jul to Aug to be compare with Sep Ach and get the result in next column

Comment: So first you Get **Highest Ach Jul to Aug**, now do you want to compare it with **Sep Ach** Or with **Highest Aug to Sep**, Because last statement in your comment is confusing ?

Comment: @NadeemAfzal, Hi I have updated the query, could you please try this?

Comment: @alpeshjikarda I want highest of achievement from "Highest Ach of Jul to Aug" and "Sep Ach".
Okay I'll try the query and update you in morning.

Comment: @alpeshjikarda I have tested the above, it works fine. I have modified it a bit to get the desired results.